# Otimizar DataTable

Tags: jquery-datatables

Estou usando DataTable para renderizar minhas tabelas. 
Mas agora estamos com mais de 1mi de dados na BD.
Alguém teria como me ajudar com isso? Estou tentando utilizar a documentação da DataTable mas não estou conseguindo.
Na verdade consegui, mas percebi que em um dos campos, por conter mais textos, a query não funciona. Não é um erro de query, pois se faço direto (sem DataTable) funciona.
Obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: Uma dúvida, você está enviando 1 milhão de registros de uma vez para o DataTable?

Comment: Sim... Trata-se de uma base de cadastro de produtos. Os clientes foram cadastrando, cadastrando e agora estamos com essa quantidade de registros...

Comment: Com o DataTable é possível eu paginar a Query, como se faz com o LIMIT?

Comment: Então é simples resolver, em vez de enviar todos os registros em apenas uma vez, limite a entrega por exemplo a 100 produtos. Utilize a paginação via webservice ou, como cita a documentação do DataTable, via server side. Segue link da documentação: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html. Se prosseguir para este lado, conseguirá resolver a questão de performance sem problemas.

Comment: É justamente nessa página que parei... Não consegui entender como fazer isso... O que devo fazer no "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php" é um PHP que retorne um JSON como no exemplo?

Comment: Sim, o server_proccessing.php seria o que devolveria os dados. Nele você receberá as variáveis para criar a paginação, dê um print na $_GET e $_POST para ver os dados que ele lhe envia. Com esses dados, você consegue fazer a paginação sem problemas.

Comment: Ok Bruno, muito obrigado.

Comment: Achei esse link: https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/ com um exemplo completo em PHP, dê uma olhada, talvez ajuda a entender como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Eu Resolvi da seguinte mandeira:

```css
#tableClientes {
            max-width: 1237px !important;
            display: block;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

o problema desse método, é que eu tive que atribuir um valor limite em **PX**, para o minha table, já que usando **%** não dava certo.